# How can I hide code from the Edge browser in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have developed a *dummy* React application using `create-react-app`.

[Stackbliz Reference](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-code-sample)

I know that when we do `npm run build` a build is created and there are `map` files included in the build. The map file maps between the transpiled JavaScript file and the original source file.

So I tried deleting the `map` file and it didn't work. Also, I feel this is not the right way. So I wanted to know how to hide the code from the browser in Dev Server.

[image]

I tried using the `package.json` with `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false`, but it still didn't do the trick.

Comment: You *deleted the map files and it didn't work?* What does that mean? What's your definition of "work"?

Comment: I searched for a solution and I saw that people were suggesting deleting the map file which is generated on build for the code to be not visible in the browser

Comment: Well, so you did that, now what did you expect that to do and how did you confirm that it didn't do that?

Comment: I don't want the users to see the code rendered on the browser via debugger tools or inspecting elements. I have added an image for reference.

Comment: It’s weird that it’s still mapping the source code when supposedly you have discarded the map files. Caching problem…? Are you serving via the development server? — Either way though, you are aware that the user will see *some* code anyway; it just shouldn’t be as pretty without the map files.

Comment: Yes, This is Development Server and I understand it's easier to debug with the code but there is a requirement in our project where they are going live with the Dev Server itself. So before its Live, I want to hide the code

Comment: Don't go live with a dev server…?! Why would you do that?! Anyway, if that's your requirement, make that clear in the question. The dev server serves live-compiled code, it doesn't serve the files created by a build.

Comment: Even though its Dev Server, I have moved the Build folder to a different location Dev Server and accessing that folder only in the browser and not the one from `npm run`

Comment: Actually Your question is Wrong , but i Suggest the Server Side rendering (SSR) ,Just search it... :)

Comment: If it will be run by the browser, you can’t hide it from the browser (and the browser will not let you hide it).   Best you can do is run an obfuscator on it to make it hard to read. (Or switch to server side rendering and don’t use in browser code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` this will hide your code in browser

```
"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build",
```

for production use env name `.env.production`

for dev use env name `.env.development`
and command to run build `npm run build:dev`

```
 "build:dev": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts build",
```

- if you have same `env` for all environment or don't have `env` remove `.env.production` and `.env.development` from script

BEFORE -----
[image: before GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false]

AFTER ----- [image: AFTER GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false]

Answer (score 5):

For `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` you can try creating a .env file and put it in that or you can try running `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false npm start` or `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false npm run build`

Comment: This will stop the map files from generating but I am saying that it doesn't work even after deleting the map files manually.

Answer (score 3):

Create a file `.env.production` in your project directory (where package.json is located).

Then put in there:

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=TRUE
```

Anorher way is `package.json` file:

```json
    scripts: {
      "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"
    }
```

And third is a command line use:

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build
```

I recommend using .env.production file.